# jQuery selector :contains - Use regular expressions

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I am trying to implement search functionality for a list using jQuery. I am using following line to filter matching elements

```
$(list).find("a:contains(" + filter + ")").parent().show();
```

This shows all the elements which contain "filter" text. I want to show only those elements in which words start with "filter" text.

I am thinking of using regular expression for this.

Is there any way to pass regular expression to `:contains` selector? Or can this be achieved in any other way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use `.filter()`, but the good news is you don't need a regular expression:

```
$(list).find("a").filter(function () {
    return (this.textContent || this.innerText || '').indexOf(filter) === 0;
}).parent().show();
```

Comment: +1 for being the first and use of `this.textContent || this.innerText` :)

Comment: awesome solution! :D If you need the regex though, just change the return statement to `return (this.textContent || this.innerText).match(some_regex);`

Comment: Plus on to cancelledout...your's solves the "use a regex requirement" of this question