# jquery What to use for exact match rather than contains

Tags: jquery, exact-match

I have a function that scans a table for a variable (keyID) and selects the table cell that contains that variable. The variable is currently defined as:

```
selectedTD = table.find('td:contains("' + keyID + '")');
```

However if keyID = 10, then selectTD will return a value if a table cell contains 10, 100, 1010 etc.

How can I make the variable selectTD only select the table cell when keyID is an exact match, rather than contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()` to pass each item in the collection through a function that returns true if the item should be included:

```
selectedTD = table
                .find('td')
                .filter(
                    function() { 
                        return this.innerText === keyID 
                    });
```

ETA: 
If you can control the HTML generated I suggest you add the keyID as a `data-` attribute such as `<td data-keyid="keyhere">`. Then you can simply use `$('td[data-keyid=' + keyID + ']')`

Answer (score 1):

There's no single, native jQuery selector that will let you do that, but [good answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309763/jquery-selector-contains-use-regular-expressions).  Alternatively, [this jQuery extension](https://gist.github.com/Mottie/461488) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like:

```
selectedTD = table.find('td').filter(function(){
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML) == keyID;
});
```

Comment: @Madbreaks yeah, re-reading the question, I think you're probably right. Edited.